# Capturing the Paste option from the context menu in AS3 Air Application

Tags: actionscript-3, air, paste

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. User right clicks on a textfield, the system menu that shows the options of "cut,copy,paste,delete,Select All" appears (with only "Paste" and "Select all" active)
2. User clicks on "paste"
3. The pasted text is added to the textfield.

My issue is being able to run code **right after** the user selects the "paste" option from the contextmenu. I tried listening to the textfield change, eventchange, to no avail. This is the code I am using. When the above happens, the following code does not fire. "d" is the textfield object

```
    d.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, paste);


    private function paste(e: Event): void {
        trace("paste event fired");
        if(Clipboard.generalClipboard.hasFormat(ClipboardFormats.TEXT_FORMAT)) {
        trace("pasted data is ", String(Clipboard.generalClipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.TEXT_FORMAT)));
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:

I tried the suggestions below, but still no luck. Here is the code I have. "d" is already added to stage

```
    private function start():void {
           d.addEventListener(TextEvent.PASTE, paste);
    }
    private function paste(event:TextEvent):void{
           trace("something got pasted");
    }
```

What's bugging me is that event is not firing for whatever reason

Comment: Not clear.. Are you saying you can do step (2) but not step (3)? What actually happens when user clicks "paste" vs what is expected result? Just trying to build a picture of problem..

Comment: I can do 1,2, and 3. what I could not do is  listen to the paste event. Say, if the paste event included the text "XYZ", I would like to run code based on the pasted text. I hope this makes it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`TextField`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html) is an [`InteractiveObject`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html), which has a [`paste`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event:paste) event. You can listen for it with the [`flash.events.Event.PASTE`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#PASTE) constant.

EDIT: Apologies, the `paste` event documentation says it doesn't work with `TextField`. It recommends using the Flash Text Engine, though that is difficult and I don't know how to do text input with it.

You could try:

1. The [`textInput`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#event:textInput) event.
2. The `paste`, `change`, and `textInput` events with a [`TextInput`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/TextInput.html) component instead of a `TextField`.
3. The `paste`, `change`, and `textInput` events with a [`TextArea`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/TextArea.html) component instead of a `TextField`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Kyle, but the way the application is designed, I can not change the textField to TextComponent. Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: UPDATE: Just realized what was going on. The event listener was registered to a different object, and I was clicking on the wrong object all along. My bad, and thanks for your help @Kyle